# How to create an in memory eml file with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eml

How can I create a client side in-memory eml file? I've come across numerous suggestions. But none, out of the box, work in my setup. Namely where

- the code that creates an eml file resides in a NodeJS library
- browserify is used against this library to generate a bundle.js
- bundle.js is used to make this behaviour available in a browser

Some of the technics I've investigated but discounted so far

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eml-format

https://github.com/BramEsposito/eml-to-pdf

Depend on the 'fs' module which browserify complains about

https://www.example-code.com/nodejs/email_examine_eml.asp

Licenced

https://github.com/nodemailer/mailparser

Looked promising but specific to reading existing emails not creating them.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types

Is not used to create eml files.

https://github.com/ikr0m/mime-js

Looks promising but I've yet to get it to work.

Comment: .eml files seem to use MIME RFC 822 file format. Try searching for that instead.

Comment: Good tip. Believe they're a mix of RFC 822 and RFC 1521.

Comment: What about [https://github.com/moll/js-internet-message](https://github.com/moll/js-internet-message)?

Comment: Looks like an option. I'll give it a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settled upon the emailjs-mime-builder

https://github.com/emailjs/emailjs-mime-builder

Answer (score 0):

Nodemailer with [stream as a transport option](https://nodemailer.com/transports/stream/) allows you to create ".eml" files